# Text doesn't appear in MovieClip after added as child. What's wrong with my ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm pulling data from external XML. i created a sprite to serve as container for my pages. Those pages are movieclips which i then add each of them to stage as child to container using a for loop. For each movieclip i will add text & images which i will then animate using greensock. but the problem now is a simple text wont appear when i export swf movie. i have no problems loading external xml files and what not. i dont believe this to be a xml or loader problem. where did i go wrong? :~( .I believe i imported all the necessary package too.

```
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.display.Stage;

public class menu extends Sprite {

    protected var container:Sprite = new Sprite();

    public function buildPages(e:Event):void {
        var menu:XML=new XML(e.target.data);
        menu.ignoreWhitespace=true;
        container.x = menu.config.frxpos;
        container.y = menu.config.frypos;
        addChild(container);

        var i:Number;
        totalPages = menu.pages.page.length();

        for(i=0; i<totalPages; i++) {
            var pageMc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            pageMc.name = menu.pages.page[i].@name;
            pageMc.id = menu.pages.layoutNum.layNum[i];
            container.addChild(pageMc);
            pageMc.x = 100;
            pageMc.y = 100;
            pageMc.width = 200;
            pageMc.height = 200;

            pageNames[i] = pageMc.name;
            pageLayoutNo[i] = pageMc.id;

            if(pageMc.name == "registration") {
                var myTxt:TextField = new TextField();
                myTxt.text = menu.pages.intro.htext;
                myTxt.textColor = 0xff0000;
                myTxt.x = 150;
                myTxt.y = 150;
                myTxt.border = true;
                myTxt.borderColor = 0x747474;
                pageMc.addChild(myTxt);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Is the problem in the registration conditional? Have you tried tracing out "menu.pages.intro.htext"?

Comment: yes, i can trace out menu.pages.intro.htext with no problem